# How can I remove duplicate, invalid, child nodes from an XML document using Linq to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I'm creating XML from JSON retrieved from an HttpWebRequest call, using JsonConvert. The JSON I'm getting back sometimes has duplicate nodes, creating duplicate nodes in the XML after conversion, which I then have to remove.

The processing of the JSON to XML conversion is being done in a generic service call wrapper that has no knowledge of the underlying data structure and so can't do any XPath queries based on a named node. The duplicates could be at any level within the XML.

I've got to the stage where I have a list of the names of duplicate nodes at each level but am not sure of the Linq query to use this to remove all but the first node with that name.

My code:

```
protected virtual void RemoveDuplicateChildren(XmlNode node)
{
    if (node.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element || !node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        return;
    }

    var xNode = XElement.Load(node.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree());
    var duplicateNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        var isBottom = this.IsBottomElement(child); // Has no XmlNodeType.Element type children

        if (!isBottom)
        {
            this.RemoveDuplicateChildren(child);
        }
        else
        {
            var count = xNode.Elements(child.Name).Count();

            if (count > 1 && !duplicateNames.Contains(child.Name))
            {
                duplicateNames.Add(child.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    if (duplicateNames.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var duplicate in duplicateNames)
        {
            xNode.Elements(duplicate).SelectMany(d => d.Skip(1)).Remove();

        }
    }
}
```

The final line of code obviously isn't correct but I can't find an example of how to rework it to retrieve and then remove all but the first matching element.

UPDATE:
I have found two ways of doing this now, one using the XElement and one the XmlNode, but neither actually removes the nodes.

Method 1:-

```
foreach (var duplicate in duplicateNames)
{
    xNode.Elements(duplicate).Skip(1).Remove();
}
```

Method 2:-

```
foreach (var duplicate in duplicateNames)
{
    var nodeList =  node.SelectNodes(duplicate);

    if (nodeList.Count > 1)
    {
        for (int i=1; i<nodeList.Count; i++)
        {
            node.RemoveChild(nodeList[i]);
         }
     }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you modify your question, nobody who has read the post will know. You may need to do a new question at that point. Comment on one of the answers if you were borrowing from their material, so they will know how to clarify their answer.

Comment: You need to do two things in your code, verify that `duplicateNames` has all the duplicate names, and two that your `xNode.Elements(duplicate)` is getting the nodes you want to remove. Otherwise look at my answer below, to see how to modify your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want any duplicate names: (assuming no namespaces)

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // .Parse(string)
List<string> names = root.Descendants().Distinct(x => x.Name.LocalName).ToList();
names.ForEach(name => root.Descendants(name).Skip(1).Remove());
root.Save(file); // or root.ToString()
```

Comment: Presumably that "root.Save(file)" is what I'm missing, but I don't have the file, just an XML string that I've loaded into an XmlDocument at the start of the processing. The XmlNode I pass into the method is a child of that document. Perhaps that's the key, I should update my XML after manipulating the document.

Comment: Yes, that's it, my XmlDocument was updated but I'd missed the step of converting that back to the string. I'll update my node removal code to us your more efficient version. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to solve the problem at the wrong level. In XML is perfectly valid to have multiple nodes with the same name. JSON structures with duplicate property names should be invalid. You should try to do this sanitation at the JSON level and not after it was already transformed to XML.

For the xml cleanup this might be a starting point:

```
 foreach (XmlNode child 
   in node.ChildNodes.Distinct(custom comparer that looks on node names))
{
.....
}
```

Comment: I had thought of doing the sanitation at the JSON level but how would I do that? I have no control over the creation of the JSON, I am only consuming the response from a service call.

Comment: i'm not saying about the creation but when you parse it with JSONConvert. Just walk the resulting structure and remove duplicates. That should be a more clean approach than doing the same thing at the xml level

Comment: AZ, which class should I use to walk through the JSON structure before conversion to XML? My method above is working well with the XmlNode class but I can't find an equivalent for JSON.